# Select rows where pivot has ALL ids

Tags: mysql, select

**Case**:
I want all companies that have company_id 8 and 13, but ONLY if they have ALL product_ids (1,2,4,8).

**Problem**:
company_id 13 does not have product_ids 4 and 8, but still shows up in the results of the query as below. It seems as though cp.product_id IN (1,2,4,8) returns the company if it has ONE of these values, but I need them to have ALL these values in pivot table company_products.

```
SELECT
    c.id as company_id,
    cp.product_id
FROM
    `companies` as c
    LEFT JOIN `company_products` cp ON cp.company_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.id IN (8, 13)
    AND cp.product_id IN (1,2,4,8)
GROUP BY
    c.id
```

My guess is I should use something other than IN, but my research has not lead me to the correct solution. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "_all companies that have company_id 8 and 13_", Is it right to assume you actually meant "_company_id 8 OR 13_"? The boolean and/or is what's important here, and `IN ()` operates as an `OR`. That part of your question I understand, but clarification is needed for the other `WHERE` condition.  It would help if you provide a sample of input rows together with a sample of output rows from that input so we don't have to make any inferences.

Comment: In my code I have already determined I want company_id 8 AND 13. I want to filter these two companies on the criteria of having all the given product_ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `having` clause to your query to make sure that every group of c.id has all four cp.product_id:

```
SELECT
    c.id as company_id
FROM
    `companies` as c
    LEFT JOIN `company_products` cp ON cp.company_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.id IN (8, 13)
    AND cp.product_id IN (1,2,4,8)
GROUP BY
    c.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cp.product_id) = 4;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23670/3)

If you need the product details too you can use the above query as a derived table and join it with the product table.

Comment: This solution works, although it seems in this solution, I'll be using an extra clause where instead I should (or could) be using a different operator than IN. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: This is the common solution to this problem, because you need a group to determine if all are present, and `HAVING` is applied after the group. There's no way to apply it directly in `WHERE` because that is still operating per-row.

Comment: @ChrisHessler As far as I know there isn't any operator that would do what you want as the where clause operates on a row but you want to evaluate several rows at once (for which you have to use group by/having). The alternative would be to use multiple joins to the company_product table instead, but it would be inefficient. With some other databases using `intersect` would have been another (sub par) option.

Comment: Seems legit. Thank you kindly for your solution and both your feedback. I will use this solution.