# Find parent where child in array

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I've got two tables,

1. Places
2. Products

What I am trying to achieve is to find ***Place*** By multiple ***products***.
So basically.

```
find PLACE where product ids in [1,4,6]
```

The thing is that it looks for every place where product id = 1 OR id = 4. I want to find a place that contains all the products. So 3 conditionals must be achieved.

This is how it looks in sequelize

```
const eq = await Place.findAndCountAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: PlaceProduct,
      as: 'products',
      where: {
        productId: [1,2,5]
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

And it returns places which contain only of the required products.

I want all to be required.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how IDs work! IDs are supposed to be unique. How can a fruit be apple and banana at the same time?

Comment: Say what? I think you misunderstood the question. Relation many to many. Think about it as car and the car parts. 

You have Place X, Place Y.

Place X contains Product ID 1 and product ID 3.

Place Y contains Product ID 1 and product ID 2

Comment: So basically you are looking for places that _have all those products_.

Comment: Exactly. Still working on that, so if you have any tip - just shot.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used the Sequelize library. If raw query is an option, here is a related question: [Select rows where pivot has ALL ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106843/select-rows-where-pivot-has-all-ids)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the count of records are exact of `product_ids` , if yes then thats the record you want , and if is less than that it will be ignored

```
const product_ids = [1, 2, 5];

const eq = await Place.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: PlaceProduct,
        attributes : [],
        as: 'products',
        where: {
            productId: product_ids // <----- product_ids
        }
    }, ],
    group: ['place.id'], // <--- Not sure but , you might need to add place_product.id also here
    having: {
        $and: [
            db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.col('place.id')), product_ids.length), // <----- product_ids
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did before you commented. Thank you